# How do I reference a jQuery UI Widget on a page and call a function on it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the [ui-multiselect](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) widget to render a `<select>` list differently.

I'm trying to reference a new function that I added to the widget, but its not finding the reference.

My newly styled  list is rendered fine on the page, using the following HTML:

```
<select class="multiselect" id="MySelect" multiple="multiple" name="MySelect">
<option value="1">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
<option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

I then added a function to the code for the widget:

```
...
    destroy: function() {
        this.element.show();
        this.container.remove();

        $.widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    myNewFunction: function() {
        alert('hello world');
    },
    _populateLists: function(options) {
        this.selectedList.children('.ui-element').remove();
...
```

In my javascript code, I want to make a call to this function, but I can't seem to get the reference correct. Here's what I'm trying:

```
$('#MySelect').myNewFunction();
```

It doesn't find that function on the object that gets returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$('#MySelect').multiselect('myNewFunction')`.

`$('#MySelect')` just gives you the DOM element. `$('#MySelect').multiselect()` should give you the widget control.

(I haven't used jQuery UI yet, but this seems to be the idiom from other questions and the little bit of documentation that I've seen).

Comment: No, that didn't work. Still says that myNewFunction() is not found.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I spoke too soon. I'll give you credit if you want to update your answer. You got me halfway there. It actually turned out to be $('#MySelect').multiselect('myNewFunction')

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jquery extension methodology in order for jquery to pick up that method as a viable extension, something like the following.

```
$.multiselect.fn.extend({
    myNewFunction()
});
```

you'll need to extend the multiselect.

start [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.extend) to get more information